# Reproduce an problematic email on basis of the email source

Tags: email, sap

we have some problems in Jira related to emails send from two SAP Systems.
The mails won't process properly, i assume because they have a null body.

Unfortunately the SAP Systems sending the emails are not ours and we have no control over them and cannot trigger the sending of these emails.

Therefore i am wondering:
Is there a software / online service to which i can supply the source of an email message and then have the service send exactly that email again?

I am aware that there would be issues with the fact that the SMTP used by the service / software is not in charge of the sending domain, but i think we could handle that.

Cheers
Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an online service for that. SMTP is fairly simple; it would take a few lines of Python to submit a message using *smtplib* (same for most other programming languages), and probably even less to do it by hand through `telnet` or `netcat` (but there are caveats so I don't recommend this).

For example, *swaks* is an existing program for directly talking to SMTP servers. Normally it just fires off a canned "test message", but you can provide your own message contents like this:

```
swaks --server foo.example.com --from "sender@foo" --to "recipient@bar" --data message.eml
```

---

Note that SMTP delivery does not look at "From:/To:" headers in the message data; it has separate *envelope* 'from' and 'to' parameters which you need to supply yourself.

(Headers are strictly for display, while SMTP envelope is strictly for delivery. The two don't always have to match, and in fact, it might be better to supply *your own* `--from` address depending on how your system performs SPF & DMARC anispam checks.)

---

Here's a Python example:

```
import smtplib

sender = "sender@foo"
rcpts = ["recipient@bar"]
data = open("message.eml", "r").read()

with smtplib.SMTP("foo.example.com") as conn:
    conn.sendmail(sender, rcpts, data)
```

Likewise, there's Net::SMTP for Perl, PHPMailer for PHP, Lettre for Rust, etc.

Comment: Hi Grawity,
Thanks for your reply.
I get swaks to send mails but i am having trouble sending my problem e-mail.
I think i have my email in the wrong format,
when i send it i just get the source.
The source is a text file containing the headers and the base64 encoded mail.
kind regards
Jens

Comment: That's exactly the same format as used by SMTP (also known as the RFC2822 format). You'll need to be more specific about what problems you're having...